# java.lang.ClassCastException:Jboss resteasy logging

Tags: java, rest, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am using Jboss7.0.1 Final to deploy my web application, But I don't want to use default Resteasy jar provided by Jboss so I made the changes in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding
            some dependencies -->

        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="org/apache/xml/security/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
            <module name="com.mrf.portal.configuration" />

            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"
                services="import" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <!-- This one always goes last. -->
            <module name="javax.api" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now project deployed successfully but when this code call.

```
 static {

    try {
      client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

It is throwing below exception:

> 07:19:11,034 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11 01
>   2016 07:19:11,033 DEBUG DocumentProvider:60 - Unable to retrieve
>   config: expandEntityReferences defaults to true
>
> 07:19:11,053 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11 01
>   2016 07:19:11,052 DEBUG DocumentProvider:60 - Unable to retrieve
>   config: expandEntityReferences defaults to true
>
> 07:19:11,095 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11 01
>   2016 07:19:11,094  WARN RegisterBuiltin:103 - ClassNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load builtin provider:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.CacheControlInterceptor
>
> 07:19:11,116 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11 01
>   2016 07:19:11,115  WARN RegisterBuiltin:103 - ClassNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load builtin provider:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.ClientContentEncodingHeaderInterceptor
>
> 07:19:11,139 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11 01
>   2016 07:19:11,138  WARN RegisterBuiltin:103 - ClassNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load builtin provider:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.ServerContentEncodingHeaderInterceptor
>
> 07:19:11,287 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mdf-portal-web].[Faces
>   Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for
>   servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.logging.impl.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to
>   org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:92)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.YamlProvider.(YamlProvider.java:42)
>   [resteasy-yaml-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar:]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:148)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2175)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:748)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1366)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1310)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.registerProviders(RegisterBuiltin.java:70)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:31)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.getProviderFactory(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:309)
>   [resteasy-client-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:317)
>   [resteasy-client-3.0.8.Final.jar:]     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.mdf.soa.portal.integration.rest.Constants.(Constants.java:200)
>   [mdf-portal-integration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:897)
>   [classes:]     at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.LoginBean.verifyLogged(LoginBean.java:1150)
>   [classes:]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2464)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]     at
>   javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2116)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:288)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

Comment: Have you tried using somethng like this? -<exclude-subsystems>
   <subsystem name="resteasy" />
  </exclude-subsystems>

Comment: there is a similar answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329767/jboss-6-3-0-decent-way-to-remove-resteasy-and-use-jersey