# Wildcard to exclude multiple JBoss modules in jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Tags: java, jboss, module, jboss7.x

Is there any one-liner solution to exclude multiple JBoss modules in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` packed in the application `war`?

Current:

```
<exclusions>
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />
</exclusions>
```

Desired (something like):

```
<exclusions>
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.**" />
</exclusions>
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Exclude_a_Subsystem_from_a_Deployment.html), you just need something like `<exclude-subsystems><subsystem name="resteasy" /></exclude-subsystems>`. No wildcard needed.

Comment: If you exclude the subsystem entirely but need some modules from it anyway, these have to be specified. More details here - https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Did my suggestion helped?

Comment: @aribeiro No, it seems not to be working. Basically, I am trying to exclude javax.ws.rs as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32614208/4754790). For example, when I exclude it from module dependencies with `<module name="javaee.api" />`, everything works fine. But when I exclude it with `<exclude-subsystems><subsystem name="javaee" /></exclude-subsystems>`, it seems to have no effect (I get library mismatch errors like `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class`).

Comment: @aribeiro Does it work for `war` packaged applications? Is it possible that subsystem exclusion works only for `ear`s, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, I've found a JBoss forum post that perhaps may solve your problem. Care to try [this approach](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2975)?

Comment: @aribeiro Thanks. I am trying this on EAP 6.2, so I think that version should not be a problem.